# Q1. Why my ProjectWraper Component is Getting duplicated for each unique porject record in projects[ ] array Q2. Project Component wont render?

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to Reactjs and trying to develop a portfolio website.

Q1. the **`ProjectWrapper`** component is being duplicated for each unique project record in the **`projects`** array due to the rendering logic in the **`Projects`** component. The **`Projects`** component is using the **`projects.map`** function to iterate through each project and render the **`ProjectWrapper`** component with the corresponding project data.

Q2. the **`Project`** component is not rendering on small screen devices whlie testing using Devtools when there are more than seven records in the **`projects`** array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
 import { Tilt } from "react-tilt";
 import { motion } from "framer-motion";
 import { textVariant, fadeIn } from "../../utils/motion.js";
 import { styles } from "../../styles.js";
 import github from "../../assets/tech/github.png";
 import { SectionWrapper } from "../../hoc";
 import { projects } from "../../services/services.js";
 import Slider from "react-slick";
 import "../../css/style.css";
 import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
 import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
 
 const ProjectCard = ({
   index,
   name,
   description,
   tags,
   image,
   source_code_link,
 }) => {
   const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

   return (
     <motion.div variants={fadeIn("up", "spring", index * 0.5, 0.75)}>
       <Tilt
         options={{
           max: 45,
           scale: 1,
           speed: 450,
         }}
         className={`bg-gray-800 p-5 rounded-2xl sm:w-[360px] w-full ${
           isHovered ? "expanded" : ""
         }`}
         onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
         onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
       >
         <div className='relative w-full h-[230px]'>
           <img
             src={image}
             alt='project_image'
             className='w-full h-full object-cover rounded-2xl'
           />

           <div className='absolute inset-0 flex justify-end m-3 card-img_hover'>
             <div
               onClick={() => window.open(source_code_link, "_blank")}
               className='black-gradient w-10 h-10 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer'
             >
               <img
                 src={github}
                 alt='source code'
                 className='w-1/2 h-1/2 object-contain'
               />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>

        
           <motion.div
             className='mt-5'
             initial={{ height: 60 }}
             animate={{ height: "auto" }}
           >
             <motion.h3
               className='card text-[#d1d5db] font-bold text-[24px]'
             >
               {name}
             </motion.h3>

             {isHovered && (  //Render description only when hovered
             <motion.p
              className='text-[#d1d5db] mt-2 text-secondary text-[14px] text-justify ${isHovered ? "expanded-content" : ""}'
              initial={{ scaleY: 0 }}
              animate={{ scaleY: isHovered ? 1 : 0 }} // Scale Y-axis to 1 when expanded, 0 otherwise
              transition={{ duration: 0.3, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
             >
               {description}
             </motion.p>)}
            
           </motion.div>

         <div className='mt-4 flex flex-wrap gap-2'>
           {tags.map((tag) => (
             <p
               key={`${name}-${tag.name}`}
               className={`text-[14px] ${tag.color}`}
             >
               #{tag.name}
             </p>
           ))}
         </div>
       </Tilt>
     </motion.div>
   );
 };

 const ProjectWrapper = ({ index, projectIns }) => {
   const elementRef = useRef(null);
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(elementRef.current);
     const element = elementRef.current;
     const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
       ([entry]) => {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
           element.classList.add("tilted");
         } 
       },
       { threshold: 0.5 }
     );
     observer.observe(element);
     return () => observer.unobserve(element);
   }, []);

   return (
     <div ref={elementRef} key={`project-${index}`} className={'tilt-on-view'} >
       <ProjectCard key={`project-${index}`} index={index} {...projectIns} />
     </div>
   );
 };

 const Projects = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   }, []);

    return (
     <section className={`mt-12`}>
       <motion.div variants={textVariant()}>
         <p className={`${styles.sectionSubText} `}>My work</p>
         <h2 className={`${styles.sectionHeadText}`}>Projects.</h2>
       </motion.div>

       <div className='w-full flex'>
         <motion.p
           variants={fadeIn("", "", 0.1, 1)}
           className='text-white mt-3 text-secondary text-[17px] max-w-6xl leading-[30px]'
         >
           The subsequent projects exemplify my proficiency and expertise by providing tangible instances of my work in the real world.
           Each project is succinctly described and accompanied by links to its code repository and live demonstrations.
           It reflects my ability to solve complex problems, work with different technologies, and manage projects effectively."
         </motion.p>
       </div>

       <div className='mt-20 flex flex-wrap gap-7'>
          {projects.map((project, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <ProjectWrapper key={index} index={index} projectIns={project} />
            </div>
            
          ))}
       </div>
     </section>
   );
 };

 export default SectionWrapper(Projects, "projects");
```

new to React don't know what to do

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.